# In Square, when we mark an Order as Ready, is there any way to get Square to notify that user via email or text?

Tags: square

With the new API, it is great that we are able to push orders to the POS app - now I just need a way to notify customers that the pick-up is ready.  I have my own system seperately right now, but is there any way to do this inside of Square. Or even better, is there any way to hook into a square event?

I see webhooks, but only things like payment, refund, dispute events.  Is there any way to catch an order status change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are webhooks for different order update events:

[image]

You could then create some webservice of lambda to process such webhook payload, and submit an email using some 3rd party email sending solution.

There is a challenge that since you will need to query the square api for the rest of order details, you will need to create a `square app`, implement `oauth` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's currently no Order webhooks at this time. Webhooks are definitely an area Square's APIs have been focusing and improving lately, so I suspect this to be an area we continue to improve. With that said, there is no ETA on if/when this is coming, sadly we do not share public timelines.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but it's the answer